# List index Convert into datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have stored datatable at index 0, and int at index 1 in a List, now i want to convert list index 0 into datatable.. How it will get converted into datatable?

```
//Class Function
      public List<object> Login(string A, string B)
        {

           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           xConn.Open();
           SqlCommand xComm = new SqlCommand("Ulogin");
           xComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           xComm.Connection = xConn;
           xComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", A);
           xComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", B);
           int usercount = (Int32)xComm.ExecuteScalar();
           xComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
           new SqlDataAdapter(xComm).Fill(dt);
           List<object> L = new List<object>();
           L.Add(dt);
           L.Add(usercount);
           return L;
        }


       //Web Form
       protected void Sub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        string Email = TextBox3.Text;
        string Pass = TextBox4.Text;
        List<object> L = d.Login(Email,Pass);
        int I = Convert.ToInt32(L[1]);
        if (I > 0)
        {
           //How does it convert here?
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Incorrect Email Or Password");
        }

     }
```

Comment: `(DataTable) L[0];` or `L[0] as DataTable`

Comment: If its always two length and index 0 and 1 always do same job then use `Tuple<T1,T2>` instead of list. Reduce complexity of your code. Also in this case you dont need cast.

Comment: Or even beyond using a Tuple, use a custom class to represent the data. A `List<object>` in this case requires special knowledge of what is in the List and isn't very descriptive of your intent.

Comment: @austinwernli thanks :)

Comment: i'm beginner, i never used tuple that's why i used list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable) L[0];
```

For further reference, see: [Casting and Type Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173105(v=vs.100).aspx)